# Codeigniter query Always returning TRUE

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I got this piece of function that updates  an account with 1 or 0,
note that the account_status has a data type of boolean.

I understand that $this->db->query(); returns TRUE or FALSE in write queries,

but i am having trouble, because when i tried to put a non boolean value on account_status, still the response is success, but obviously it will not update because the data is not boolean.

```
public function approve_account($id='0'){
        if($id == '0' OR $id== ''){
            return FALSE;
        }else{
            try{
                $id = (int)htmlentities($id,ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8');
                $sql= "UPDATE elibrary.elib_user_account e 
                       SET account_status = 'hg' 
                       WHERE t_user_id = ?
                       LIMIT 1;";

                if($this->db->query($sql,$id) === TRUE){
                    echo 'sucess';
                }else{
                    echo 'FAIL';
                }
            }catch(Exception $e){
                echo $e;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i dont know why you ppl use direct queries when the framework is giving you active classes

Comment: If query is executed successfully ("successfully" does not mean your expected behavior) it will return `true`. Run your query manually and see if phpMyAdmin or Workbench will return any error. If there will be just warning that no rows were affected it's probably ok for `codeigniter`.

Comment: @VIPINJAIN I had situations where I had to run too complicated query containing some business logic. In this situations it's ok to run query string directly. I don't say that this's that situation.

Comment: @plb i found out what is wrong, its Ianzz answer below, thank you

Comment: @PLB: OK, so thats what the thing is. :).. BUT one more thing is that active classes is made like that they can handle any type of business logic. and one more thing is that codeigniter is unsafe :O

Comment: @VIPINJAIN, how exactly is CI not safe??

Comment: its session handling and data security is very bad. you can see this by using its session only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL does not have a native `boolean` type, booleans are represented as `tinyint(1)`. Storing string values in a numeric column would coerce them to a numeric value — in your case, the string `'hg'` is not a valid integer, and is coerced to the value `0`, which is stored in the `account_status` column and further interpreted as `false`. If your string contains a valid number, e.g. `'5'`, it would be stored as the integer value `5`, which is considered `true` for boolean operations.

Comment: so after many hours, i conclude yes, this is what is happening to me right now, so its not about the query, its about the logic how i structured my database, thank you  i think i found another way out of this.

Answer (score 3):

Try this , Number of affected row

If it gives 0 then no row affected.

`$this->db->affected_rows()`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `mysql_errno()` to get information regarding SQL errors from mysql.
You should do it just after the `query` command.

```
if (mysql_errno()) {
```

This way you will be able to give the user real information regarding the cause of the error